# Integrating Python Selenium Results to JIRA

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pytest, jira

I am working on a project and daily running the 100's of test cases which are developed on Python. Till now we were manually updating the status in JIRA. But we want to automate this process. I am not sure whether below one is the right documentation or not
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/

I am using pytest framework. I have gone through some videos and documents but everyone is following different methodologies. If someone can suggest me with the recommended documentation and as well as how can I implement this in the pytest framework.

Thanks in Advance

Referring multiple documents and I am confused little.

Looking for a right documentation link i.e., the recommended documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xray integration with Jira to update the status of Test type Jira ticket based on nightly run in Jenkins. You need to add Xray plugin in Jenkins and Xray integration in Jira. Create a Test Execution ticket in Jira
where all Test type Jira ticket needs to be added for which u want status to be updated.